# "sed" re-write a file to show integers and remove remaining characters

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed, grep, ping

I aim to produce an output which can be used to develop an average based on 5 server ping's. I'm running:

```
ping 8.8.8.8 -c 5 > ping.txt
```

which outputs

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=0 ttl=46 time=29.331 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=1 ttl=46 time=34.057 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=2 ttl=46 time=33.978 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=3 ttl=46 time=33.629 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=4 ttl=46 time=48.414 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 29.331/35.881/48.414 ms
```

Then, I aim to remove the textual data surrounding the time in ms for each ping to the server, at the moment, I have:

```
sed 's/".*time=//' ping.txt > pingres.txt
```

Which doesn't quite remove all the data I require and outputs as follows:

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
29.331 ms
34.057 ms
33.978 ms
33.629 ms
48.414 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 29.331/35.881/48.414 ms
```

I would like to show the data in the following way, but have forgotten some principles of sed to achieve this and am quite the novice..

```
29.331
34.057
33.978
33.629
48.414
```

I realize, there's already an average marked, at the bottom of the file, but I require this method for other reasons

Comment: @Theophrastus I can't use perl on the platform I'm running unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a bit more filtering with `grep` to limit the lines you're looking at:

```
$ ping 127.0.0.1 -c 5 | grep "bytes from" | sed -n -e 's/^.*time=//' -n -e 's/[^0-9\.].*$//p'
0.020
0.040
0.054
0.036
0.049
```

Comment: also removes the need for me to use two files, thanks pal

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -m5 -oP '\stime=\K\d+\.\d+(?=\s+ms$)' ping.text

sed -ne '2,6s/.* time=\([^ ]*\) ms/\1/p' ping.text
```